# View UI hierarchy is empty in view debugger in Xcode 7.3

Tags: xcode7.3

I Updated Xcode 7.3 from Xcode 7.2
In Xcode 7.2, the view debugger is been worked well.
But, in Xcode 7.3, the view debugger does`t showing any views when I trying to use it .
If I clicked Debug View Hierarchy button, the View is clean.

Comment: I think the OP is saying that tapping "Debug view hierarchy"  in Xcode 72. was showing the layers of the views [like this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/Art/IB_ViewDebugging_2x.png), while tapping the same button on Xcode 7.3 shows nothing.

Comment: Yes, you're definetely right, Antonis.
And, I'm so Sorry about my low English level..

Comment: Same here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36313850/debug-view-hierarchy-in-xcode-7-3-fails

Comment: I'll check it.
Thank you for your answer, orkenstein.

Comment: In my case, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37185961/2160799) was helped.

Comment: No reason to close this question, i have same problem.

Comment: @luky Did you try this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/37185961/2160799