# Debug view hierarchy in Xcode 7.3 fails

Tags: xcode, swift

This function fails with runtime error:

```
-[UIWindow viewForFirstBaselineLayout]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fb9dae257d0
```

Anybody encountered the same?

**UPD:**
Fails on simulator iOS 8.1/8.4. 9.3 works fine.

**UPD2:**
`UIWindow` is created like:

```
window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)    
window?.rootViewController = RootViewController.rootVC
window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Comment: what kinda deal do you do with the `UIWindow`, anyway?

Comment: No deal at all. The User Interface Inspector fails on its own.

Comment: I am facing up the same problem now,looking for solutions

Comment: @orkenstein, which iOS version did throw such exception to you?

Comment: @holex, get this on simulators ios 8.1/8.4. Version 9.3 works correct.

Comment: how do you create your `UIWindow` instance? could you share that knowledge as well?

Comment: @holex, check **UPD2**.

Comment: for me also stopped working on 8.4 simulator

Comment: Have you tried testing on a device (e.g. iPhone)?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I got the view debugger working again by placing the following fix in my project:

```
#ifdef DEBUG

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@implementation UIView (FixViewDebugging)

+ (void)load
{
    Method original = class_getInstanceMethod(self, @selector(viewForBaselineLayout));
    class_addMethod(self, @selector(viewForFirstBaselineLayout), method_getImplementation(original), method_getTypeEncoding(original));
    class_addMethod(self, @selector(viewForLastBaselineLayout), method_getImplementation(original), method_getTypeEncoding(original));
}

@end

#endif
```

When your project loads, the `load` method will execute, causing `viewForFirstBaselineLayout` and `viewForLastBaselineLayout` to use the `viewForBaselineLayout` implementation if they are not currently implemented, so view debugging gets iOS8 flavor the behavior it was looking for.

To add this to your own project, create a new empty Objective-C file in your project and paste the contents in.  You can name it whatever you want.  I call mine "UIView+FixViewDebugging".  If you are in a pure Swift project you **do not** need to create a bridging header.  The file will be compiled into your project and you don't need to reference it.

Note this will only work for debug builds because of the `#ifdef DEBUG`.  You can remove it but then you may accidentally compile this into your release builds (though it should have no ill side effects).  If this method isn't working with these lines, check that your target has `DEBUG=1` in Build Settings > Apple LLVM - Preprocessing > Preprocessor Macros > Debug.

Comment: Still broken as of Xcode 7.3.1 (7D1014), with or without the swizzling above, even in 9.3 (13E230) Simulator.

Comment: Worked for me on XCode 7.3.1

Comment: Didn't work for me in XCode 7.3.1, iPhone 6s iOS 9.3.2.

Comment: This piece of code might not work when you (like in my case) don't have the DEBUG flag enabled. Removing `#ifdef #endif` might solve your problem.

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler Thanks, I've added that to my answer.

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly with Xcode 7.3.1 and iOS 8.1 simulator.

Answer (score 21):

Looks like Xcode 7.3 uses `viewForFirstBaselineLayout` property to draw the UI. But this property is marked as available since iOS 9.0.

[image: Screenshot of UIView.h]

`[UIView viewForFirstBaselineLayout]` method should be used for the version prior to iOS 9.0. It seems the guys from Apple didn't consider this case.

Comment: That's correct, once I switched to iOS 8 simulator, the error happens and switched back to iOS 9, no more error.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. when click the debug view hierarchy button  ,the page  has nothing, and print "[UIWindow viewForFirstBaselineLayout]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fb9dae257d0"  .

To solved it,  just be sure you are  using the iOS systom not below iOS 9.0 and  you will still use that function  freely.