# Xcode 7.3 iOS 8 simulator debug view hierarchy is blank

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8, ios-simulator, xcode7.3

The debug view hierarchy tool in Xcode 7.3 is only working on iOS 9.3 simulators. When I try using it on iOS 8.2 simulators, the debugging view is a blank white screen. Is anyone else seeing this?

Comment: Yes. Seems like 7.3 "hidden feature".

Comment: Please file a radar at http://bugreport.apple.com

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Debug view hierarchy in Xcode 7.3 fails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36313850/debug-view-hierarchy-in-xcode-7-3-fails)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, I'm seeing the same thing - just a blank screen when running (in my case) 8.4 simulators, but works fine w/ iOS 9.  This is particularly annoying because the problem I'm trying to debug behaves differently under iOS 8!

Comment: Thanks for confirming Jeff.

Comment: I wouldn't accept this answer, because the same issue appears also on iOS 9.3.3. It doesn't seem to be related to iOS version.

Comment: Same here for iOS 9.3 ... DVH is working for same project on another machine

Answer (score 3):

I'm on Xcode 8.2, but I had this same problem.

I had been using the "Nvidia Web Driver" rather than the OS X Default Graphics Driver. When I switched back to the OSX driver and did a reboot, this feature started working for me again.

Comment: Hackintosh with Nvidia Web Driver faced same problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using "Nvidia Web Driver" you can use the following kext below.

[NVWebDriverLibValFix](https://github.com/mologie/NVWebDriverLibValFix/releases) by [mologie](https://github.com/mologie)

run these command and restart:

`sudo tar -xv -C /Library/Extensions -f ~/Downloads/NVWebDriverLibValFix.kext.1.0.0.tar.gz
sudo kextutil /Library/Extensions/NVWebDriverLibValFix.kext`

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17449253)

Comment: Sorry.I've just changed my answer.Hope it can help.

Comment: Hackintosh user here + Nvidia web drivers: this solved my problem perfectly

Answer (score 0):

I have found that on a system that doesn't support Airplay, (older Mac Pro) it doesn't work. On one that does support Airplay, it seems to work just fine.